# Intro to building scalable public web services (ref)

Tags: web, architecture

I have experience building small, internal web applications.

I'm looking for a good **beginners introduction** to the subjects of

1. Scalable web architectures (ex. what are the basic pieces?)
2. Managing public-facing web systems (ex. statistics, monitoring, alerting)

Most of the material I can find assumes knowledge of either (1) or (2) - I know neither.

**Edit:** Looking for an introduction to the underlying concepts and principles as opposed to "use [company]'s [product] for [problem]"

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft published a book on this look here:
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=16236